# SQL merging rows with different column data

Tags: sql, merge, row, partition

I am trying to create a table on Snowflake SQL showing users using specific products. The problem I have is that I have duplicates with people with different usernames. I would like to merge the rows by taking out the username after matching with the products, and then keep the yes's and remove the no's.

[image: Example Rows to be merged BEFORE]

[image: Example Rows to be merged AFTER]

The usernames are required when creating matching to products, but I only want one row per user.

Partition by seems to be the closest description of what I am looking for, but it takes an entire row and removes the other, can't seem to find a process that keeps YES.

Comment: perhaps `max()` and `group by`

Answer (score 0):

To merge the rows by taking out the username after matching with the products, and then keep the yes's and remove the no's you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function